# Прямая речь. Постановка знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

**Обратимся к тексту Ю. Бондарева, где выражено подтверждение этому. К примеру, отец словами летящими из его души поведал Надежде, что для него счастье : " Все живы, нет войны, все в сборе в моем доме - вот я и счастлив!".**

Не понимаю правильно расставил знаки при прямой речи да и правильно в предложение поставил?

Comment: Редактирование вопроса: Правильно ли я поставил знаки препинания при оформлении прямой речи, а также   в самом предложении?

Comment: Кроме того, что есть пунктуационные ошибки, предложение требует редакторской правки. Я бы обратил внимание на следуюшие места: "выражено подтверждение",  "к примеру", "отец словами". И вообще, весь этот пафос ("летящими", "поведал"),  на мой взгляд, неуместен по отношению к ситуации и к простым и искренним словам отца.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В Вашем тексте я бы заменила вводное сочетание "к примеру".
2. Необходимо выделить запятыми причастный оборот ("летящими из его души"), который стоит после определяемого слова.
3. Точка после кавычек не нужна.
4. Остальная пунктуация верна.

*Обратимся к тексту Ю. Бондарева, где выражено подтверждение этому. Например, отец словами, летящими из его души, поведал Надежде, что для него счастье: " Все живы, нет войны, все в сборе в моем доме — вот я и счастлив!"*

Answer (score 1):

**Предлагаемый вариант текста:**

Обратимся к тексту Ю. Бондарева, где выражено подтверждение этому. Так,  отец "летящими из его души словами" говорит Надежде, что для него счастье: " Все живы, нет войны, все в сборе в моем доме ― вот я и счастлив!"

1) В предложение вставлена цитата, изменен порядок слов, точка в конце прямой речи не нужна (уже есть восклицательный знак).

2) Тире ставится для обозначение бессоюзной связи перед частицей ВОТ, так как последнее предложение имеет значение вывода по отношению к первым трем предложениям.

Comment: Arina, (1) Как вы относитесь к тому, чтоб поставить запятую после "отец" ("словами, летяшими из его души" – пояснение)? (2) Почему после воклицательного знака стоит точка?

Comment: Точка, конечно, не нужна.  Мне кажется, что в текст вставлена цитата, и ее надо выделить кавычками. А структура предложения  не очень удачна, чтобы оно "читалось", надо его как-то перестроить (обособление - не лучший вариант). Попробую предложить изменение текста.

Comment: Еще я заменяю вводные слова (например, к примеру).  Они достаточно объёмные, со словом "отец" фонетически не сочетаются (приходится делать паузу) и поэтому   "мешают" сразу перейти к основному содержанию текста.

Comment: Я вообще не уверен, что это "к примеру" оправдано по смыслу. "Так" гораздо уместнее и по смыслу, и, так сказать, по ритму.